# Unclosed tags and Nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby, xml, parsing, nokogiri

My test html file is here: http://pastebin.com/L88nYbQY

As you can see there are some unclosed input tags, and some self closing ones.

This causes the following code to return everything from the opening #qcbody div to the end of the file, ignoring the closing div tag.

```
require 'nokogiri'

f = File.open('t.html', 'r')
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)
@doc.at_css('#qcbody').to_html
```

I'm sure people have gotten around this problem in a variety of ways. How would you do it?

Comment: Having never looked at this before, but glancing at the documentation, I would guess "Use Nokogiri::HTML to parse HTML and leave Nokogiri::XML for parsing XML" (Noting that XHTML that is not well formed is an invalid abomination that is unsuitable for XML parsers). (But that is just a guess)

Comment: Thanks, but `Nokogiri::HTML` only parses the HTML header.

Comment: Actually, I think you're right, David. My issue seems to be with the version of libxml. On a system with libxml 2.7.7, Nokogiri::HTML works, but on a system with libxml 2.6.26, it only returns the html tag.

Comment: libxml has had some bugs that affected Nokogiri's ability to parse. Previous versions of Nokogiri would raise a message complaining about it until you acknowledged the issue wasn't Nokogiri's but in libxml. So, trying to upgrade libxml is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

@doc = Nokogiri::HTML(File.open('t.html', 'r'))
@doc.at_css('#qcbody').to_html
```

In IRB:

```
>> @doc.at_css('#qcbody').to_html
=> "<div id="qcbody">         \r\n    <form method="post" name="form" id="form" action="#">\r\n      <input type="hidden" name="Search Engine" id="Search Engine"><input type="hidden" name="Keyword" id="Keyword"><input type="button" onclick="javascript:validate()" name="sendsubmit" id="sendsubmit" class="submit">\n</form>\r\n    <div class="clear"></div>\r\n  </div>"
```

The difference between using `Nokogiri::XML` and `Nokogiri::HTML` is the leniency when parsing the document. XML is required to validate and be correct. Some XML parsers would reject an XML file that doesn't meet the standard. Nokogiri allows us to set how picky it is. (And in the case of XML, you can look at the [`errors`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html) array after parsing to see if there is a problem.)

For HTML, Nokogiri relaxes the parser so there's a better chance of handling real-world HTML. I've seen it handle some really ugly markup and keep on going when lesser parsers blew their lunch. If you look at [`Nokogiri::HTML.parse`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/HTML.html) it has [`options = XML::ParseOptions::DEFAULT_HTML`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/ParseOptions.html) defined, which are the relaxed settings. You can override that if you want to make sure the HTML conforms.

Answer (score 1):

```
@doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(f)
@doc.at('#qcbody').to_html
```